How to copy files between Windows and Linux host using Ansible?
I have following infrastructure:

Windows host win_host in Ansible inventory running Win Server 2022
Linux host lin_host with some files I would like to copy
Ansible running in Kubernetes AWX container on separate Linux host awx_host

I have Ansible playbook which should do the following:

Add the host B to the playbook (that works)
Copy a file to host A from host B (this doesn't work)

I tried many variation of following task:
    - name: Fetch file to the destination host
      ansible.builtin.copy:
        src: /tmp/another.txt
        dest: C:/
        remote_src: yes
      when: inventory_hostname == 'win_host'
      delegate_to: lin_host


I tried delegating to different hosts
I tried copy/fetch/win_copy
Remote/local source
when: different hosts

I just can't figure out the correct combination of parameters to use. Any idea how to do this or if it is event possible?

I would think the only way that ansible.builtin.copy would work is if the Windows Server is running OpenSSH server. You would then have to specify the credentials of a user on the Windows Server in your playbook.  The other option would be to have the smbclient installed on the linux host.  Mount the Windows Share.  Then copy the file to the mounted share.

I'd start small and then combine the steps. Just copy some sample file from your local machine to the windows machine with whatever method you like. Does this work? Fetch the files from the linux machine. Does this work? Then start combining... Maybe you have already done that? Then give us some detailed feedback about what works and what not... This is how I would debug and build...
